# I have try to build ionic app with sdk 31 but i got error below error. Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: ionic-framework, javac

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRqlO.png)

I have try to build ionic app with sdk 31 but i got error below errer.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
21 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 19 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\galaxy_app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\galaxy_app\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I have try below step

ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android@10

ionic repair

Delete node.module and package-lock and run npm install.

no any work for me.